# ssh_exchange_identification: unprotected port

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh, sshd, minix

I wanna login a guest `minix` system resides inside VirtualBox through `ssh` and receive the error `ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host`.

After turn on the verbose flag, the complete output is:

```
OpenSSH_5.5p1 Debian-4ubuntu6, OpenSSL 0.9.8o 01 Jun 2010
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 127.0.0.1 [127.0.0.1] port 5000.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/id/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/id/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/id/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.DSA-1024
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.DSA-1024
debug1: identity file /home/id/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: ssh_exchange_identification: \001/usr/bin/in.rshd: unprotected port (39852)

ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

The `/usr/bin/in.rshd` is an ssh server on `minix`. I can't figure out what's going wrong. What may be the problem?

Comment: Are you completely, absolutely sure `in.rshd` is a **SSH** server? It seems that it is using the *rsh* protocol -- expecting connections from a privileged port, and returning a *rsh* error message instead of the SSH handshake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that's an ssh server you're connecting to.  It appears to be an [rsh server](http://www.minix3.org/manpages/man8/rshd.8.html), rsh being a predecessor of ssh that didn't have ssh's encryption or strong authentication features.